# Python environment not set using Make file (Unix)

Tags: python, unix, yaml, conda, virtual-environment

I am trying to setup the environment in my Unix terminal. When I run my yaml file with make, I am getting the error

```
make: *** [Makefile:105: environment-dev] Error 247
```

But when I remove conda-forge from yaml file, all my packages are getting installed but in the end I am getting the error

```
Adding activation of '/home/xxx/yyy/.env' to conda 'env-abc' environment...
/bin/sh: 1: .: Can't open /home/xxx/yyy/.env
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
```

Please find the below yaml file

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python==3.7.1
  - pip:
    - -r src/requirements.txt
    - jupyterlab==0.35.*
    - flake8==3.7.*
    - -e .  # The project package.
```

Command I used:
make filename

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

My Bad. I just create .env file and it worked well.